# Need help creating a view with two different pet sums

Tags: t-sql, join, count, sum

I am trying to create a view that creates a table that gives the sum of dogs and the sum of cats. 
This is what I currently have. But I am not sure how to get into a view format.

```
select count(PetType) as [Amount of Dogs]
from Pets
where pettype = 'dog'

select count(PetType) as [Amount of Cats]
from Pets
where PetType = 'cat'
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW v AS
SELECT * FROM
(select count(PetType) as [Amount of Dogs] from Pets where pettype = 'dog') d
CROSS JOIN
(select count(PetType) as [Amount of Cats] from Pets where PetType = 'cat') c
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when PetType = 'dog' then 1 else 0 end) as num_dogs,
       sum(case when PetType = 'cat' then 1 else 0 end) as num_cats
from Pets;
```